# If a field in a gauge theory is covariant is that the same as the covariant derivatives of the field are 0?

Tags: derivatives, covariance, gauge-theory

If a field in a gauge theory is covariant is that the same as the covariant derivatives of the field are 0? I'd like a formal answer, coordinate free. E.g. the covariant derivative can be written as
d \pm [A\wedge ] for some connection 1-form A

Comment: I am definitely not an expert, but isn't the covariant derivative of the field typically an element of the Lie Algebra of the gauge invariant transformation group?

Comment: I thought it should be another field but the covariant derivative with respect to an element of the Lie Algebra of the gauge invariant transformation group?

Comment: What is your definition of a field being "covariant"?